# .Net Web API service to read sensor's information from Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspberry-pi, mosquitto

I am a beginner with raspberry pi 4 and I would appreciate any help.
I am making a simple project in .net – basically I have a web APi service which should read raspberry Pi device sensor’s indications. I have read that the simplest communication between my Web APi service and the raspberry Pi sensors is setting up an MQTT broker to act as an IOT server
Have somebody tried this and is it a simple process. Also is this a simple code, should I write the commands in Python. I saw that most people use mosquito as it is easy to install on Pi.https://mosquitto.org/. In my web APi c# project I will use an MQTT library to send (publish) AND RECEIVE messages(the sensor indications) to that broker. The question is – would it be hard to send this sensor's information from the Raspberry to the broker with the sensor indications.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is fragmented:

What sensors are you reading?
Do you need mosquitto? Depending on what you want to do, frequency of calls, concerns about transport performance or payload size etc. You may or may not require an MQTT broker, in the case that you need one, you can build one in .Net with MQTTnet or similar.

You say you're starting out but you have or know how to build a .Net Web API, in that case I say stick to what you know and decide if you want to go the mosquitto route later.
If you have a .Net Web API, you can write python requests against your .Net Web API.
That's easy-peasy as python isn't hard to get started with.

If you want to stick to .Net and you are more comfortable with it, explore Mono or run VS Code https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToInstallVisualStudioCodeOnARaspberryPi4InMinutes.aspx and some have even loaded .Net Core.

At your own risk you can even explore experimental options like Windows 10 Arm and Windows IOT Core as options, then you should be able to run .Net apps on them.

Comment: sorry I didn't have enough time to work on the project.  I want to create a service listener which in every ten minutes should get dht22 - temperature and himidity sensor indication, and as I don't have any time my goal basically is what is the easiest way to get this type of sensor's indication in .net every ten minutes, You can write to me on my mail - thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

In your case you definitely don't need mosquito/mqtt transport. The delay is long enough to just use your regular .Net Web API.

Combine the following tutorials:
https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-humidity-sensor-dht22/
https://www.w3schools.com/python/module_requests.asp

Ideally you want to post the data but for example sake here is a get request.

Python example:

```
x = requests.get('http://localhost:5000/api/raspberrypi?sensorId=1&temperature=22.5&humidity=34')
```

Your .Net Web Api Endpoint:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(int sensorId, double temperature, double humidity)
{
  var timeStamp = DateTime.Now; //Date & Time of receiving reading.
  // Your save code here
}
```

Note, I included a field for sensorId in case you have several sensors sharing the controller.